# RSS Feed Viewer Sharepoint 2010 Webpart stopped working

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, rss

I have a RSS view webpart in Sharepoint 2010 portal, till last day it was working fine. Now it's throwing the error.

“The requested RSS feed could not be displayed. Please verify the settings and url for this feed. If this problem persists, please contact your administrator.”

We didnt have any proxy server, and RSS feed link is not a Secured HTTP. The RSS feed is working fine, i can able to view the data through browser. Please help me to sort it out.

I also need to know, what is causing this error

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the WFE you are accessing has acces to the internet.  The RSS Viewer WebPart is using server side processing to render the feed, so it needs an acces to the web.

Comment: Also ensure that there are no firewall rules that can be blocking the RSS site.  Try hitting the URL directly in IE on the Web Front End.

Comment: If the RSS feed uses authentication then check if kerberos is working fine.